# Function that includes string and float and I call it from main. But error

Tags: c

I am a newbie and I just write a function and call it from main. But error return.

I have tried compiling it but error

```
#include <stdio.h>

void data(char name, char address,float

     salary);

    int main()
    {
        char name[] = "john";
        char address[] = "london";
        float salary=10000000;

        data(name,address,salary);

        return 0;
    }

    void data(char name,char address,float salary)
    {
        printf("Name : %s\n",name);
        printf("Address : %s\n",address);
        printf("Salary : %lf\n",salary);
    }
```

some warning messages I dont understand.
I thought it should be working. What's going on?

Comment: your function has char as function parameters yet you are passing a char[]

Comment: well acually it compiled. But when I execute it, it just told me "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: my desired result is:    Name : john  Address : london   salary : 10000000

Comment: Please include the warning messages in the question (formatted as code using the `{}` button).

Comment: cekfun.c: In function ‘main’:
cekfun.c:11:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘data’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  data(name,address,salary);
       ^~~~

Comment: `%lf` is technically right but the proper printf format specification is `%f` and it's also the one that would be right for scanf too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passing to the data function an array of character (string) but in the function declaration you initialize them to receive a char variable.

you should change the declartion to:

```
void data (char name[], char address[], float salary)
```

or:

```
void data (char *name, char *address, float salary)
```

Comment: well done sir. It actually works. But I still dont fully understand why I am getting wrong, and why should "*" this symbol appears?  what C concept should I grasp related to this? many thanks..

Comment: "*" this sign is an pointer, this type of variable is received an address, when you write it in a function declaration it means that the function should received an address, and array name is actually holding the base address of the array. it means that you sending the base address from the main to the function.

Answer (score 0):

`void data(char name, char address, float salary)` expects `char` types for name and address while you are passing char[] type.

In `void data(char name, char address, float salary)`, %s expects a string from name and address but these are only 1 character without null character indicating end of string.

Change to `void data(char *name, char *address, float salary)` to solve the problem.